# Django pass get parameters from login to users home page

Tags: python, django

My login url is like this `http://localhost:8000/?wid=ca1480&ref_url=localhost&adpart=left`

When a users log in through login page and come to his dashboard his url should be like this

`http://localhost:8000/dashboard/?wid=ca1480&ref_url=localhost&adpart=left`

But i am unable to achive this what changes i need to make.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', LoginPageView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^dashboard$', login_required(DashboardPageView.as_view()), name='dashboard'),
```

**Views.py**

```
class LoginPageView(FormView):
  template_name = 'login.html'
  form_class = LoginForm
  success_url = '/dashboard'

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:

            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
            else:
                return render(request, self.template_name, {
                    'error':'Invalid Username and Password, Please try again.','form': form
                })
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Wrong Email and Password combination.")
            return self.form_invalid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)



class DashboardPageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'dashboard.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.GET
        url = reverse()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#views.py
...
success_url = self.get_success_url()
if request.META.get('QUERY_STRING'):
    success_url += '?' + request.META.get('QUERY_STRING')
return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
...
```

I would also recommend to replace

```
success_url = '/dashboard'
```

with:

```
from django.core import urlresolvers
...
success_url = urlresolvers.reverse('dashboard')
```

Comment: Where i should put the above code in views.py under Dashboard ??

Comment: in place of return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

Comment: You might miss some indentation, replacement code assumed the same indentation as the replaced one.